# Polymer: Checkbox elements not being updated after changing the checked property

Tags: polymer, javascript-databinding

I am writing a sample program in polymer. I have a template as shown below:

```html
<template is="dom-repeat">
   <li class="clearfix title-container">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="{{item.checked::change}}" class="checkbox-container float--left" />
      <label class="label-container">{{item.id}}</label>
   </li>
 </template>
```

I have a button as shown below on click of which function f1() is called:

```html
<button on-click="f1">Save</button>
```

**Initially all the checkboxes are checked.** The user might uncheck some of the checkboxes and then click on the button. f1() collects all the elements that have been checked by the user. After execution of f1, **I want all the checkboxes to be checked again**. The code for f1() is shown below:

```js
//Collect all the selected items in a separate array.
//Revert unchecked checkboxes to checked.
f1: function() {
  newIndex = 0;
  for (index = 0; index < this.dataArray.features.length; index++) {
    if (this.dataArray.features[index].checked) {
      this.newDataArray.selectedElements[newIndex++] = this.dataArray.features[index];
    } else {
      this.dataArray.features[index].checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

The following is the definition of dataArray element (I just printed it in a console):

```js
//The dataArray when printed in a console
{
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: Array(4)
}
features: Array(4) 0: {
  type: "Feature",
  checked: true
}
1: {
  type: "Feature",
  checked: true
}
2: {
  type: "Feature",
  checked: true
}
3: {
  type: "Feature",
  checked: true
}
```

The problem I am facing is that after f1() executes the changes made to the checked property are not reflected in the UI even though I have assigned all the values in the array to be checked. I have read about sub-properties not being reflected directly but I don't understand how do I use a notifyPath() here or how do I use the array mutation methods. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array mutation methods.. Polymer isn't noticed about changes in arrays, so you have to call [notifyPath](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/classes/Polymer.Base#method-notifyPath) or just use [array mutation methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data) .